# Finding list index number in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was working with huge lists of prime numbers in Python and was trying to find the position number (as in 2 for the y in this case -> `[x,x,y,x]`) of a prime in the list by referencing it elsewhere:

```
primelist = [104395303, 104395337] #it's a lot longer than that but you get the idea
print([primelist].index(104395303))
```

I was hoping for this to return 0 - i.e. the position of the `104395303` in the list called *primelist* but got the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    print([primelist].index(104395303))
ValueError: 104395303 is not in list
```

Screenshot for evidence at my troubleshooting attempts.

[image: here]

Why am I receiving this error? What should I do to achieve my desired target other than what I've already tried?

Comment: Only remove [ ]. **print(primelist.index(104395303))**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
primelist.index(104395303)
```

It's already a list. Don't wrap it in another list.

Comment: It will throw an error if element is not found in the list

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if it exists before running .index

```
primelist = [104395303, 104395337]
index_check = 104395303 in primelist
if(index_check):
    print(primelist.index(104395303))
else:
    print("Number not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use python `if else` block to get index if present else `-1` if not present

```
primelist = [104395303, 104395337]
num=104395303
index_= primelist.index(num) if num in primelist else -1 #index_ would be 0
```

if else would be useful for the case if the element is not present in the list for example `num=104395303` if we do `primelist.index(num)` it will throw `ValueError` as the element we are trying to find does not exist already but with `if else` block we can assign index as `-1` if element not found.

```
primelist = [104395303, 104395337]
num=104395304 # num not present in list
index_= primelist.index(num) if num in primelist else -1 #index_ would be -1
```

Or wrap your code in `try except block`

```
primelist = [104395303, 104395337]
num=104395304
try:
    index_= primelist.index(num)
except ValueError:
    index_=-1

print(index_)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
primelist.index(104395303)
```

... should do the job.

The index function simply finds the index of the element passed. What you have done is put the list inside another. Now if you want to check the index then you would have to use:

```
[primelist][0].index(104395337)
```

Another easier method is:

```
104395303 in primelist
True
```

As this is very easy to combined with an if-condition and is extremely handy.